# SURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) Swift 3

Tags: swift3

My Code is below:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.queryItems = args.map {
    URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
}
let paramToSend = components.query!

let url = URL(string: "https://my-test-server.com")
let session = URLSession.shared

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = paramToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

    guard let _:Data = data else{ return }

    let json:Any?

    do{
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
    } catch{
        return
    }

    guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else { return }
    print(server_response)

    guard let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary else { return }

    guard let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String else { return }

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

    //                        DispatchQueue.main.async (
    //                          //  execute:self.LoginDone
    //                        )

})

task.resume()
```

The test server has the ssl certificate and I have verified it by draging to simulator. But still same error. 
I tested the call in firefox and it works fine. 
I have also updated info.plist for `Allow Arbitrary Loads: YES` 
Please guide what i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Some general advice: use safe optional unwrapping and don't use Foundation data types when they have native Swift equivalents (such as `NSDictionary`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("urlPath:==> \(urlPath) ")
let session = Foundation.URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: urlPath)
var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

do {

    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
              return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

            if let responsedata = responseString!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as? Data{

                do {

                    let jsonResult:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responsedata, options: []) as! NSDictionary
                    print("Get The Result \(jsonResult)")
                     //check your error response is null or not
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                    }

                     //check your success response is null or not
                    if let str = jsonResult["success"] as? NSNull {
                        print("error=\(str)")

                    }
                    else {
                        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                        print("Response string : \(responseString)")

                    }



                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        }) .resume()
}catch {
    //                print("Error -> \(error)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue. Just wanted to share the experience to help someone facing the same issue.

Do the following steps:

1) Add self signed certificate file (.crt) to keychain access.

2) In keychain access mark the certificate as "Always trusted"

3) Export certificate as .cer

4) Drag the .cer file to iphone simulator and install the certificate

5) In iphone simulator Goto General > About > Certificate Trust Settings and Enable Full Trust for Root Certificates

Test the app it will work now without any code changes for trusted and not trusted certificates.